# JQuery Spinner Issue

Tags: jquery

In my form where this code resides, the spinner functions fire each time the optionForm div is clicked. The first click works fine and fires the alerts once. Click again, and they fire twice. Third click fires three time, etc. Where is the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#optionForm").click(function() { 

    $("#process").hide().ajaxStart(function() {
        alert("show")
        $("#process").fadeIn('100');    
    })   
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        alert("hide")
        $("#process").hide();
    });

    $.post('post_requests.php', {

        scenario: ($('#scenario:checked').length ? 1 : 0 ),
        toolkit: ($('#toolkit:checked').length ? 1 : 0 ),
        newsletter: ($('#newsletter:checked').length ? 1 : 0 ),
        scenarios: $('#scenarios').val(),
        tools: $('#tools').val(),
        news: $('#news').val(),
        submit: 'yes'}, function(data) {

            $("#optionResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100');

            FadeMsg();

        }, 'text');

    function FadeMsg() {

        waiting = setInterval(function() {
            $('#optionResponse').fadeOut(500);
            },3000);    
    };

    clearInterval(waiting);
    return false; 

});         
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the [**ajaxStart**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and **[ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/)** calls outside of the click handler.

If you keep them in the click handler you are adding a new callback to be executed each time a new ajax request starts or stops.

The documentation even has an example similar to what you're trying to do that says:

> Show a loading message whenever an Ajax request starts (and none is
>   already active).

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you subscribe with a function every time the optionForm is clicked.

Try this instead.

```
$("#process").hide().ajaxStart(function() {
        alert("show")
        $("#process").fadeIn('100');    
    })   
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        alert("hide")
        $("#process").hide();
    });
$("#optionForm").click(function() { 
    // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

every time u click the `optionForm` div the click event is fired and it attaches a new ajaxStart event to the `$("#process")`.
 so the first time u click it one event gets attached.
 and it works fine.
 next time u click it one more event gets attached and it fires two times.
.
instead u shud attach the `ajaxStart()` and .`ajaxStop()` event in advnace and not when callign the click function